# content_tag do with multiple parts using concat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I am using Rails 3. I am trying to do this in a helper:

```
def headers collection
  collection.each do |col|
     content_tag(:th, col.short_name)
  end
end
```

As you can see, the idea is that this does a content_tag to generate a `<th>` tag for each element in the collection. This doesn't work because the HTML comes out as is made safe by Rails which makes it not work as HTML.

If I change it to this:

```
def headers collection
  collection.each do |col|
    concat (content_tag(:th, col.short_name))
  end
end
```

This works better. I get the correct markup in HTML, but before it I get all the markup HTML safe. So I think I am close.

I know there are other ways to do this but I wanted to try to do this in the right elegant way. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use inject and start with an html_safe empty string.

```
def headers collection
  collection.inject("".html_safe) do |content, col|
    content + (content_tag(:th, col.short_name))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I ran into this today and solved it with `safe_join`, so:

```
def headers_collection 
  safe_join(collection.map { |item| content_tag(:th, item.short_name) })
end
```